# Java cannot find symbol on variable

Tags: java, sling

I'm pretty new to Java so bear with me. I can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting
a **cannot find symbol** error on resourceResolver.resolve. When on the line above it I'm defining the variable.
Maybe this is something simple I'm missing but I can't figure this out and I feel like I've
stared at this way to long.

```
private static final String ROOTCHILD = "rootChild";

public void setResource(Resource resource) {
   this.resource = resource;
}

public void setProperties(ValueMap properties) {
   this.properties = properties;
}

public Page getRootPage() {
   ResourceResolver resourceResolver = getResource().getResourceResolver();
   return (this.properties != null)
      ? resourceResolver.resolve(
           properties.get( ROOTCHILD,currentPage.getPath())).adaptTo(Page.class)
      : null;
}
```

Comment: Just to discard the obvious: Is the class `ResourceResolver` imported?

Comment: You must define variable wihch refers this.resource.

Comment: @Barranka thanks for replying yes it is being imported.

Comment: Where does `this.properties` come from? Is `Page` resolvable?

Comment: Can you please post the exact complete error message?

Comment: Writing everything on a single line can be nice until you run into errors like this. Split out that long line and it will be obvious were the error is exactly.

Comment: @11684 just edited the post to show you were this.properties is coming from and yes Page is resolvable.

Comment: Then it is either the method `.resolve()` or the variable `currentPage`. Wait, or `.adaptTo()`, or `getPath()`...

Comment: Where is the declaration and initialization of properties? `ValueMap.get` returns a value of type `T`, which is generic. If that is not a String or an `HttpServletRequest`, it could cause a symbol not found.

Answer (score 0):

My guess here (never worked with sling and haven't used Java for a while):

I think the problem is you initialized the ValueMap `properties` so that it doesn't contain `String`s or `HttpServletRequest`s, but something else. The `.resolve()` method only accepts either a `String` or an `HttpServletRequest`. (Or **two** parameters, but you're only passing one, so that one can't be the case.) There is no `.resolve()` method found accepting the parameters you try to give it, so **that symbol is not found**!

Answer (score 0):

To see the true error, rewrite your code and compile it:

```
public Page getRootPage() {
   if( properties == null ) {
      return null;
   }
   YYYYYY resource = getResource();
   ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resource.getResourceResolver();
   String path = currentPage.getPath();
   String rootChild = properties.get( ROOTCHILD, path );
   XXXXXX rc = resourceResolver.resolve( rootChild );
   return rc.adaptTo( Page.class );
}
```